# Как добавить класс qt

Tags: qt, наследование

Как использовать функции другого класса ( нужен пример на qt ).

К примеру в классе А используется функция из B. Как использовать в B функции из А, в include класс А добавить нельзя из-за ifndef

> a.h

```
#ifndef А
#define А
#include<b.h>
class A::MainWindow()
{
//здесь объявлено то что нужно
}
#endif
```

> a.cpp

```
#include<a.h>
class A::MainWindow()
    {
    //код класса А и использование B
    }
void afun(){}
```

> b.h

```
#ifndef B
#define B
class B::QWidget()
    {}
#endif
```

> b.cpp

```
class B::QWidget()
        {}
void bfun()
{
//код   
//вызов функции из А
}
```

Как реализовать вызов функции из А и как подключить в b.h функцию А?

A *a или а.afun() не решает проблему.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97514/discussion-on-question-by-----qt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы не можем ссылаться через [#include](http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/18334/blog100.html) взаимно между файлами - это противоречит принципу её работы. Файлы должны ссылаться друг на друга "в одну сторону".

> 2. Директива #include
>      2.1. Общие сведения Директива #include ничего умного не делает, она просто целиком подставляет файл, который передан параметром директиве.
>      Допустим, мы имеем следующие исходники:

Это фундаментальная особенность C++ и с этим ничего не сделаешь. [Forward declaration](https://pro-prof.com/forums/topic/forward-reference-class), из-за почти повсеместного наследования от QObject, тоже мало полезен при работе с библиотекой.

Вы можете соеденить заранее известные сигналы и слоты из  третьего файла, например прямо в main.cpp

Comment: суть в вопроса была именно в соединении из второго к первому, а не наоборот.